# Sprite Grid Positioning issue cocosd-js 3.16

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0

I am making a 2d(25x20) grid of sprites. But somehow sprites are getting re positioned by itself.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piQSO.jpg)

```
makeLandBlocksMatrix : function () {
this.LAND_BLOCK_TAG     = 1;
var blockCounter        = 0;
var prices              = MMMapData.getPrices();
this._blocks            = MMUtility.createArray(MMConstants.totalNoRowsPerMap,MMConstants.totalNoColsPerMap);


for (var i = 0; i< MMConstants.totalNoRowsPerMap; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j< MMConstants.totalNoColsPerMap; j++){
        var block = new MMLandBlockSprite();
        block.initWithData(res.BlockBlack,prices[blockCounter],this.LAND_BLOCK_TAG);
        block.setPosition(cc.p(block.getContentSize().width*0.5 + i * block.getContentSize().width * 1.0, (this._size.height - block.getContentSize().height*0.5) - j * block.getContentSize().height * 1.0));
        this.addChild(block);
        block.setBg();
        block._bg.setOpacity(0.0);
        block.setPriceLabel();
        block._priceLabel.setOpacity(0.0);
        this._blocks[i][j] = block;
        this.LAND_BLOCK_TAG++;
        blockCounter++;

    }
}
```

}

And same code is working fine with cocos2d-x(c++).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**After lots of tweaks and googling, i just used lower version of cocos2d-html(version 3.7). And same code work as expected.There might be problem in rendering pipeline in latest cocos2d-html. And same issue persist in case we try to make Grid of UI component or Basic components(Sprite,Label) as components number increases positioning difference increases(i.e as show in reference image).**